# VS Code Remote Development using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, vscode-remote

I've setup VS Code to connect via SSH to a remote IIS server. It setup using the key based authentication so that I don’t need to enter passwords when opening VS code and connecting.

If I'm logged in directly to the windows server via RDP, I can use the command line to do GIT commands fine because I've setup the Git Credential Manager and already have that setup.

The problem I'm having is when working in VS Code with my repository stored in Azure DevOps. When performing any GIT commands either from the terminal or from VS Code's interface I'm prompted for username/password credentials. If I provide the personal access token created originally then it will work.  But I was thinking that since I'm SSH into the remote server that it would leverage the setup from the Git Credential Manager already done. I guess that’s not the case.

Anyone got any suggestions??? Thanks.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Answer (score 0):

> If I provide the personal access token created originally then it will work. But I was thinking that since I'm SSH into the remote server that it would leverage the setup from the Git Credential Manager already done.

That because the Azure devops repository is stored in the SQL database together with all the other data  instead of storing in the remote server directly.

So, even if you have SSH into the remote server, you still could not access the SQL database because it is protected by the security protocol of azure devops. That the reason why you need still provide the personal access token.

To access the azure devops repos, we need provide the certification for Azure devops not the remoter server. You could check below document for some more details:

[Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)